# Linkedin ShareArticle. Wrong URL

Tags: javascript, iis, url-rewriting, linkedin-api

When I share a job in linkedIn, the Posted job takes me to some other link and not the provided one. However, when I replace it with some fb.com, it works fine.

provided URL is the same as **window.location.href**

```
$scope.shareOnIN = function (job) {
            var description = job.details.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ''); //remove html tags
            description = description.substring(0, description.length > 150 ? 150 : description.length); //take max 150 chracters

            var windim = {
                width: 500,
                height: 500
            };
            windim.top = parseInt((screen.availHeight / 2) - (windim.height / 2));
            windim.left = parseInt((screen.availWidth / 2) - (windim.width / 2));
            windim.screenX = windim.left;
            windim.screenY = windim.top;
            windim = $.param(windim).replace(/&/g, ',');
            var url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://day-job.dk/job-detaljer/kundeservice-customer-service-medarbejder-med-energi-og-overblik-3062/';
            window.open( url, '_blank', windim);
            return false;
        }
```

it takes me to

```
 https://day-job.dk/job-detaljer/?kundeservice-customer-service-medarbejder-med-energi&amp;og-overblik&amp;3062/
```

this scheme was provided in ISS URL rewriting but I modified it but it didn't any effect. Commenting the rules just made it unstable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was perhaps due to linked Cache on LinkedIn server.

I was unable to find the solution even with the help of many experts. 
After appending any number at the end of URL, it started to open URL residing in 
 tag in the head of the page.

Fortunately, adding number doesn't affect the working of the page so it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This is because Linked-in requires login to view a Job. If you share a job URL it will be redirected to the login page and once logged in it will be redirected to the shared job page automatically.